# Does anyone know of a Crystal Reports viewer app for iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios, software-recommendation, ios-appstore

Right now I am using [Logicity](http://www.logicitysuite.com/products/logicity.html) on my PC. I would like to know if there is a way to see Crystal Reports files on iPad.

While there are ways to boot into windows and then run my file (use iTap / TeamViewer to log in to Windows and then run Logicity), I would like to know if there are any native apps, web services, which would make the process of running this .rpt file easier.

Comment: It would be terrific if someone knows of a native iOS app that does this, as my business consumes data via Crystal in large quantities on a daily basis. What we have used in the interim is a web solution called ReCrystallize, which renders Crystal Reports on the web. It's not a cheap solution though, and does depend upon MS platforms.

Comment: @Dave won't any Crystal Reports solution be on MS platforms

Comment: @Mark, for generating them, yes. For viewing them, I have the same goal as the OP. I'd love to be able to view them natively on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Report Runner Web Portal. It's a customizable web interface to run Crystal Reports. Very affordable and user friendly. The company provides excellent technical support, too.

http://www.reportrunner.com